# JSON structure for two JSON objects before parsing?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JSON and I have a rather basic question....

Here is an example of JSON that is a response from a PHP page. My intention is to have two JSON objects, Photos, and Comments. Unfortunately, my JSON is flawed and it is not formatted properly. I do not know how to structure the JSON so that I can get both objects. What should this look like, if the JSON were correct for two objects? In other words, what do I need between Photos and Comments to indicate that these are two different objects?:

```
{"Photos": [ {"Filename": "5962230079803.jpg", "PhotoID": "39"}] "Comments": [ {"UserID": "100000660901552", "Comment": "Hello!"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a comma between each element:

```
{
  "Photos": [{"Filename": "5962230079803.jpg", "PhotoID": "39"}],
  "Comments": [{"UserID": "100000660901552", "Comment": "Hello!"}]
}
```

If you're defining and parsing this JSON result, and storing it in variable `obj`, access the properties using:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(  response  ); //response is the string containing JSON
var photos = obj.Photos;    //Array of photo objects
var comments = obj.Comments;//Array of comment objects
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your array. Try this:

```
{
    "Photos": [
        {
            "Filename": "5962230079803.jpg",
            "PhotoID": "39"
        }
    ],
    "Comments": [
        {
            "UserID": "100000660901552",
            "Comment": "Hello!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON

Comment: Oh, and here `Photos` and `Comments` are Arrays. Remove the `[]` to make them objects

Comment: @BartVangeneugden Why would you turn something that seems like a perfect candidate to be array into objects?

Comment: I personally wouldn't. But I think the question was to refer to 2 'objects'. That's why I added the extra info

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one right answer, but this should do fine:

```
{
    "Photos": [{
        "Filename": "5962230079803.jpg",
        "PhotoID": "39"}], 
    "Comments": [{
        "UserID": "100000660901552",
        "Comment": "Hello!"}]
}
```

Note the added comma. **So your structure was almost there.** Now, assuming you parsed it into a variable `response`, you could access the separate parts like so:

```
response['Photos'];
response['Comments'];
```